# Select with gap in dates

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

It is possible to make a selection with a pre-defined interval of days between records, ex:

```
+------+----------------+--------+
| user | date           |  Data  |
+----- +----------------+--------+
|    1 | 2022-01-01     |   1    |
|    1 | 2022-01-02     |   5    |
|    1 | 2022-01-03     |   2    |
|    1 | 2022-01-06     |   3    |
|    1 | 2022-01-07     |   7    |
|    1 | 2022-01-08     |   1    |
|    1 | 2022-01-09     |   2    |
+------+----------------+--------+
```

`GIVE ME ALL RECORDS WITH 2 DAYS INTERVAL FOR EACH DATE`

(There may be gaps in the records at the bank as happened between `2022-01-03` and `2022-01-06`)

Result:

```
+------+----------------+--------+
| user | date           |  Data  |
+----- +----------------+--------+
|    1 | 2022-01-01     |   1    |
|    1 | 2022-01-06     |   3    |
|    1 | 2022-01-09     |   2    |
+------+----------------+--------+
```

But this value of 2 days can be changed to 7 days, 30 etc.

Currently I'm doing this manually by code, I get the start date, add + x days, do the select, add + x days, do the other select until the interval ends, but this is extremely expensive and the process takes minutes.

Is there any way to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `date`) rn
    FROM tablename
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rn MOD 3 = 1
```

Comment: Can you explain how the query works and how I change it to change the number of days in the range?

Comment: if you are adding constant no of days then, you can simply put any value at 3 as above

Comment: For 15 years, the query ran in less than 0.01s, man you are awesome

Comment: @WotonSampaio *how the query works* `ROW_NUMBER` enumerates rows in specified order (1, 2, ...). `rn MOD 3` calculates the reminder while divide by 3, so only rows with `rn = 1,4,7,10,...` will be returned.